# How to get all the contents loaded in a page url by Selenium

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have a problem to click on a button in selenium webdriver  , and thus to  get navigated to another page. Now I have figured to how to move to the URL , 
by using

```
driver.get(driver.findElement(By.id("Arrive")).getAttribute("href"));
```

But after the page is being redirected to the URl , It is not displaying the form , as it is supposed to be shown ,, and thus throwing me an error :

```
"no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"ar00_regVSN"}
(Session info: chrome=48.0.2564.109)"
```

How to get all the contents to be displayed ?

Comment: first of all if you using java write it. second whats the code after you page redirection ?

Comment: what form it `supposed to display`? what you mean?

Comment: try refresh once after navigation